# Bessel equation relation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Define Bessel function as: $$J_a(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{(-1)^n}\over{\Gamma(a+n+1)n!}}\left({{x}\over{2}}\right)^{a+2n}.$$  Where $a$ not an integer.

Need to show $$J_{a+1}(x)J_{-a}(x)+J_a(x)J_{-(a+1)}(x)=-{{2\sin(a\pi)}\over{\pi x}}.$$

Note that the Wronskian of $$W(J_a(x),J_{-a}(x))=-{{2\sin(a\pi)}\over{\pi x}}.$$

Comment: So are you allowed to use that result on Wronskian or you need to prove it also?

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
W(J_a(x),J_{-a}(x))&=J_a(x)J'_{-a}(x)-J'_a(x)J_{-a}(x)=\\
&=J_a(x)\left(J_{-a-1}(x)+\frac{a}{x}J_{-a}(x)\right)-\left(-J_{a+1}(x)+\frac{a}{x}J_a(x)\right)J_{-a}(x)=\\
&=J_a(x)J_{-a-1}(x)+J_{a+1}(x)J_{-a}(x),
\end{align}
where we have used the differentiation formulas of Bessel functions (see e.g. 10.6.2 [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6)) to pass from the 1st to the second line. Now using the formula for the Wronskian from your question, we easily obtain the seeked identity.

---

**P.S.** The differentiation formulas can be proven either directly using series representations or by verifying that e.g. $\displaystyle J'_a(x)-\frac{a}{x}J_a(x)$ satisfies the same differential equation as $-J_{a+1}(x)$ and comparing their behaviour as $x\rightarrow 0$.