# Wronskian of Bessel Functions at $x =1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

If $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are any two solutions of Bessel's equation of order $\alpha$, then the Wronskian $W(x;u,v)=\dfrac{c}{x}$ (See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692273/how-can-you-find-the-wronskian-of-bessel-functions)).

I am trying to calculate $c$ for when $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are $J_{\alpha}$ and $J_{-\alpha}.$ The answer is $$W(x;J_{\alpha},J_{-\alpha})=-\dfrac{2}{x} \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha)},$$ but I can't reach to that! That is how to evaluate $$W(x;J_{\alpha},J_{-\alpha})= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}}{n! m!} \dfrac{x^{2m+2n-1}}{2^{2m+2n}} \dfrac{2(n-m-\alpha)}{{\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)\Gamma(n-\alpha+1)}} $$ for $x=1$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bessel equation relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443284/bessel-equation-relation)

Comment: @Nosrati, Salam. It definitely is not a duplicate. It doesn't give a proof for $W(J_a(x),J_{-a}(x))=-{{2\sin(a\pi)}\over{\pi x}}.$ It's easy to move from $-{{2\sin(a\pi)}\over{\pi x}}$ to $-\dfrac{2}{x} \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha)}$ but I don't know any one of them a proof.

Comment: Salam. I thought you have ever found the answer.

Comment: @Nosrati, No I lost internet connection that's why I replied now.

Answer (score 1):

We have from asymptotic behavior as $x\rightarrow 0$:
\begin{align}
W(J_a(x),J_{-a}(x))
&= J_a(x)J_{-a-1}(x)+J_{a+1}(x)J_{-a}(x)\\
&\sim 
\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(a+1)}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^a 
\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(-a)}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{-a-1}
+
\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(a+2)}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{a+1}
\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(-a+1)}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{-a}\\
&\to \dfrac{2}{x}\dfrac{1}{a\Gamma(a)\Gamma(-a)}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I don't know asymptotic methods, but I found an easier proof.

Comment: Very nice. .....

Comment: Also, don't worry about deleting the question if you want.

Comment: It's OK, let it be! Thanks :)